PowerBI Slicer Group
UPDATED. I want to create a Slicer Group with options (MTD,YTD) to display only rows relevant to that selection,

From the Table above, Group MTD must display columns A,B,C,D below, and Group YTD must show columns A,E,F,G.
I would appreciate any help in this regard

could you pls provide some sample data and expected output?

Updated as requested

any measures in the table? or it is the raw data?

B-G are all measures.

Can you update the data to have the Cost, Sales, and Profit for MTD and YTD in the same columns with a Period field for MTD/YTD? That would make the filtering work correctly.

here is a workaround for you.

create two pages. One is MTD. The other is YTD.

create two boxes for measure selection.
Display MTD related measures in the MTD page and display YTD related measures in YTD page.


in the MTD page, set the YTD box to page navigation and the destination is YTD page.


in the YTD page, set the MTD box to page navigation and the destination is MTD page.

then you can press Ctrl and click the box to jump between these two pages.

Ugh - why does EVERYTHING have to be a half-assed workaround in PBI? Normally you would have the measure calculation use the parameter selection but that's not possible in PBI. :(
